# How do I turn off gridlines in cartopy after declaring it?

Tags: matplotlib, cartopy

I want to add an option to turn oon/off gridlines using a function. But after once turning on the gridlines it is not possible to disable it, I tried to set xlines and ylines to False but didn't work the way it was supposed to, is there an alternative? I am using matplotlib.figure.figure instead of plt.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.coastlines()
ax.gridlines()
```

Is there any way to remove gridlines from axes?

Comment: Any feedback on my answer.

Comment: @swatchai thank you for your response, Sorry for not responding but actually I tried that way earlier and couldn't get it to work in my case. But then again I haven't tried hard, I will take another go and tell you

Answer (score 3):

To remove gridlines from plotting on the axes, you can do as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.coastlines()

# .gridlines() creates `gridliner` object
# grab it and assign it as `gl`
gl = ax.gridlines()

# manipulate `gridliner` object
gl.xlabels_top = False
gl.ylabels_left = False
gl.xlines = False
gl.ylines = False

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```py
ax.grid(False)
```

to disable the gridlines.